# Where is my lesser mana potion?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have been picking up TONS of mana potions, but I cannot find them in my inventory to take at a later time.  ( I am a wizard )  Do I automatically consume them when I pick them up?  Or are they located somewhere else (such as a passive ability) ?

Answer (score 2):

There are only healing potions in Diablo 3. The other items on the ground (they look like orbs to me) are absorbed immediately but I believe they are health related as well until you have skills that make them a bit more effective. The effects of these skills are tied to the class like Pound of Flesh for a Barbarian and Power Hungry for the Wizard that you are.

Here is a [list of the potions](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/potion/) that are in the game.

Comment: Strange... Then why do I see the mana potions drop? (not orbs)  I will try to get a screen shot the next time one drops.

Comment: @Foxtrot I see 'minor health potions' and the like and my mind reads that as mana potion for some reason, but I always see the health potion count go up.